# How can I be a better pizza deliveryperson?

Tags: pizza-frenzy

I love the game Pizza Frenzy, and I am getting really good at delivering pizzas, but I have yet to get 5 stars on any one day. What am I missing? How can I be a better pizza deliveryperson and get 5 stars every day?